# :SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, watir

I am trying to use watir and ruby to do some web scraping, but I am getting this error.[:SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1Agv.png)

On top of that, I have installed chromedriver multiple times, updated my chrome browser, and tried to use gems like chromedriver-helper and webdriver_manager. Also, the latest version of chrome seems to be 84, so I am unsure as how the program is expecting me to be on 85. My browser version is 84.0.4147.125 (Official Build) (64-bit). I am quite new to all of this, so all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I guess you are using mac, so first try to install [chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/) then run `chromedriver-update`, I'm not sure using `brew cask install chromedriver` can install or not because I'm using ubuntu :D

Comment: If you want to ask questions related to WATIR, please include watir tag

Comment: Check out your Browser version and let me know.

Comment: My browser version is 84.0.4147.125 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: So that's where the problem is! you just upgrade your browser version. And then see the version of your browser. Once you are sure of the version then you pick up the corresponding driver and use it. It will work.

Comment: There is no chrome version 85; it is still in beta. How do I change to chromedriver version 84?

Comment: It's  there, click here https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=85.0.4183.38/

Comment: I downloaded it, but how do I run it/delete the old version?

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to require the webdrivers gem, it will automatically download the right driver for your browser version. https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers/

Comment: Turn on logging and see what versions it is picking up. Webdrivers.logger.level = :debug

Comment: To clarify, the error means the driver is version 85 and your browser is 84 so it won't work. Older driver managers install shims which might cause a problem, but the logging should say what is happening

Comment: Ok, so it ran ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.38. Do you know how I can install ChromeDriver 84?

Comment: you can download chromedriver from: http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads Webdrivers gem should just work. Maybe we have a bug since we expect the driver to need to be updated to the browser version, not the other way around. (http://watir.com/guides/drivers/)

Comment: Ahh, I fixed it. It seems that I was using webdriver_manager instead of webdrivers. Once I required the "webdrivers" gem, it worked out. Thanks!

Comment: Good to know there isn't a bug. `webdrivers` bypasses the system settings to tell the Ruby Selenium code directly what binary to use, and it makes sure it is the right one.